# Nginx always responding with default index.html

Tags: nginx, deployment, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am so new for deploying things.I am just trying to deploy 2 different websites with nginx. I checked a few documents and videos but my second website which knowinapp is not working as well. Whenever I am checking the website it is showing default **index.html** or the other my website's **index.html** I don't know what I am missing.

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

**knowinapp.conf file**

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name knowinapp.com www.knowinapp.com;

       root /var/www/knowinapp.com;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `listen 82` in the second `server` block? If you are accessing the website using `http://www.knowinapp.com` it needs to be on the default port for `http`, which is 80.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the problem is about same port. So , I was  using different ports for per sites. Shall I change the config of all sites in same port to 80 ?

Comment: If you want to use the URL `http://www.knowinapp.com/` you **must** use port 80. If you use port 82, you would need to specify it as part of the URL, for example: `http://www.knowinapp.com:82/`

Comment: Okay thanks,I changed the port to 80 but my issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was about browser cache things. So, I was checked on different browser and saw the website works well... Or you can delete the cookie and site data.